xUnit test throws TypeInitializationException
I have an xUnit test project within a net8.0 Maui solution. All projects in the solution are targeting the same Windows versions (Mac and Android excluded)

I have set up the following test to check the LoadSettings method of the SettingsViewModel

When the test is run it immediately fails with the following error

I have isolated each moq but they all fail, here is the alert service as an example

Added stack trace


Are you running Windows 10 by any chance? I've no real suggestion but stumbled upon  this thread which looks related.

I am, the app runs fine and is out in production. I am retro adding unit tests, basic tests works fine, it appears to be just the DI elements

Are there any Windows updates ready to be installed for you?

There were but I have updated, still the same issue

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Tested on Windows 11, same issue

The issue was resolved by clearing down DeploymentManagerAutoInitializer.cs.
I am not sure where the file has appeared from—says it is Auto Generated—and can't find a great deal of info on it, and it also cannot be removed from the project (along with WindowsAppSdk-VersionInfo.cs).
